# C# - Button Placement inside a RichtextBox

Tags: c#, button, dynamic, location, richtextbox

I'm currently struggling with a button I want to add dynamically inside a RichTextBox.
The main issue is that I can't seem to get the location down properly (Location X & Y) also that the Text adjusts with Form Changes but the location of the Buttons won't.
The concept behind this is that I want to be able to write RTF Documents and include Button Clicks for certain Functions (Copy for now) without having to adjust the program every time.
My idea was to have a very specific Pattern -> [Copy|WHAT-TO-COPY] and replace every occurrence of this with a [C] Button in the application.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadRTF();
        AddButtons();
    }

    private void LoadRTF()
    {
        richTextBox1.LoadFile("RTF Path");
        richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    }

    private void AddButtons()
    {
        String Text = richTextBox1.Rtf;
        richTextBox1.ReadOnly = false;
        foreach (Match CopyMatch in Regex.Matches(Text, @"\[Copy\|.*\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            string CopyString = CopyMatch.Value;
            var CopyPosition = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.Find(CopyString));

            Button Copy = new Button
            {
                Text = "Copy",
                Size = new Size(20, 23),
                Location = new Point(CopyPosition.X, CopyPosition.Y)
            };

            Copy.Click += (_, args) =>
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(CopyString.Substring(6, CopyString.Length - 7));
            };

            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Find(CopyString);
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = CopyString.Length;
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";
            richTextBox1.Controls.Add(Copy);
        }
        richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

The first issue is that this method apparently doesn't work to get the proper X,Y values for the Button Creation. It seems the values don't align with the found PositionFromChar(Index).
Am I headed in the entirely wrong direction is this a proper start? What am I missing?
Also, I'm still completely new to programming so sorry if this is a total mess.

Comment: I think putting hyperlinks inside the rtf-text would make your life easier, if that is acceptable instead of buttons.

Comment: It would be acceptable for sure. I thought about doing so, just wanted to check up with the community if there is an "accessible" solution to Buttons. In the end, it would be for visuals more or less. A small copy button with a copy icon like "⎘" (or similar) instead of a blue link.  
I'll go with links, for now, to have the functionality running and come back to this topic further down the line.